# Why do many Collection classes in Java extend the abstract class and implement the interface as well?

Tags: java, collections

Why do many Collection classes in Java extend the Abstract class and also implement the interface (which is also implemented by the given abstract class)?

For example, class `HashSet` extends `AbstractSet` and also implements `Set`, but `AbstractSet` already implements `Set`.

Answer (score 41):

It's a way to remember that this class really implements that interface.
It won't have any bad effect and it can help to understand the code without going through the complete hierarchy of the given class.

Comment: +1 Additionally, the maintainer of AbstractSet might decide to change the hierarchy and remove Set for future releases (obviously not going to happen, but might happen for other non-core classes). In this case, compilation of HashSet would fail instead of all classes that use HashSet as Set.

Comment: So why not put a Collection interface too? its silly and unnecessary.

Answer (score 14):

From the perspective of the type system the classes wouldn't be any different if they didn't implement the interface again, since the abstract base classes already implement them.

That much is true.

The reason they do implement it anyways is (probably) mostly documentation: a `HashSet` is-a `Set`. And  that is made explicit by adding `implements Set` to the end, although it's not strictly necessary.

Note that the difference is actually observable using reflection, but I'd be hard-pressed to produce some code that would break if `HashSet` didn't implement `Set` directly.

Comment: +1, For example with `getInterfaces()` : http://ideone.com/BDpdr But it would be dangerous to use this method thinking that it will give all the implemented interfaces.

Answer (score 13):

This may not matter much in practice, but I wanted to clarify that explicitly implementing an interface is not *exactly* the same as implementing it by inheritance. The difference is present in compiled class files and visible via reflection. E.g.,

```
for (Class<?> c : ArrayList.class.getInterfaces())
    System.out.println(c);
```

The output shows only the interfaces *explicitly* implemented by `ArrayList`, in the order they were written in the source, which [on my Java version] is:

```
interface java.util.List
interface java.util.RandomAccess
interface java.lang.Cloneable
interface java.io.Serializable
```

The output does not include interfaces implemented by superclasses, or interfaces that are superinterfaces of those which are included. In particular, `Iterable` and `Collection` are missing from the above, even though `ArrayList` implements them implicitly. To find them you have to *recursively* iterate the class hierarchy.

It would be unfortunate if some code out there uses reflection and depends on interfaces being explicitly implemented, but it is possible, so the maintainers of the collections library may be reluctant to change it now, even if they wanted to. (There is an observation termed [Hyrum's Law](http://www.hyrumslaw.com/): "With a sufficient number of users of an API, it does not matter what you promise in the contract; all observable behaviors of your system will be depended on by somebody".)

Fortunately this difference does not affect the type system. The expressions `new ArrayList<>() instanceof Iterable` and `Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class)` still evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike **Colin Hebert**, I don't buy that people who were writing that cared about readability. (Everyone who thinks standard Java libraries were written by impeccable gods, should take look it their sources. First time I did this I was horrified by code formatting and numerous copy-pasted blocks.)

My bet is it was late, they were tired and didn't care either way.

Comment: While the source code of many default library classes is an ugly mess, the public interface of those classes is usually a lot better than the implementation (with some exceptions of course, such as the entire `Date`/`Calendar` mess).

Comment: @Joachim Maybe. On the other hand, this doesn't change the public interface. E.g., when you design whole library with pen and paper, you're not gonna draw additional line between _HashSet_ and _Set_ for "readability". So, it's still an implementation choice.

Answer (score 4):

#### From the "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch:

You can combine the advantages of interfaces and abstract classes by adding an **abstract skeletal** implementation class to go with an interface.

The interface defines the type, perhaps providing some default methods, while the skeletal class implements the remaining non-primitive interface methods atop the primitive interface methods. Extending a skeletal implementation takes most of the work out of implementing an interface. This is the [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.

By convention, **skeletal** implementation classes are called `AbstractInterface` where `Interface` is the name of the interface they implement. For example:

```
AbstractCollection
AbstractSet
AbstractList
AbstractMap
```

Answer (score 1):

I also believe it is for clarity. The Java Collections framework has quite a hierarchy of interfaces that defines the different types of collection. It starts with the Collection interface then extended by three main subinterfaces Set, List and Queue. There is also SortedSet extending Set and BlockingQueue extending Queue.

Now, concrete classes implementing them is more understandable if they explicitly state which interface in the heirarchy it is implementing even though it may look redundant at times. As you mentioned, a class like HashSet implements Set but a class like TreeSet though it also extends AbstractSet implements SortedSet instead which is more specific than just Set. HashSet may look redundant but TreeSet is not because it requires to implement SortedSet. Still, both classes are concrete implementations and would be more understandable if both follow certain convention in their declaration.

There are even classes that implement more than one collection type like LinkedList which implements both List and Queue. However, there is one class at least that is a bit 'unconventional', the PriorityQueue. It extends AbstractQueue but doesn't explicitly implement Queue. Don't ask me why. :)

(reference is from Java 5 API)

Answer (score 1):

Too late for answer?

I am taking a guess to validate my answer. Assume following code

`HashMap extends AbstractMap` (does not implement Map)

`AbstractMap implements Map`

Now Imagine some random guy came, Changed implements Map to some java.util.Map1 with exactly same set of methods as Map

In this situation there won't be any compilation error and jdk gets compiled (off course test will fail and catch this).

Now any client using HashMap as Map m= new HashMap() will start failing. This is much downstream.

Since both AbstractMap, Map etc comes from same product, hence this argument appears childish (which in all probability is. or may be not.), but think of a project where base class comes from a different jar/third party library etc. Then third party/different team can change their base implementation.

By implementing the "interface" in the Child class, as well, developer's try to make the class self sufficient, API breakage proof.

Comment: *"In this situation there won't be any compilation error"* .... wait ... you think the whole JDK doesn't use a `HashMap` as `Map<...> m= new HashMap<>()`?

Comment: @Tom


Well I was talking about a pattern. Jdk is big enough and it can be used, and in smaller set if API it may not be used. But when we publish an API, it has to be self sufficient is what I was "guessing". Apart from that, the readability and all other reasons are already listed

Answer (score 0):

In my view,when a class implements an interface it has to implement all  methods present in it(as by default they are public and abstract methods in an interface).

If we don't want to implement all methods of interface,it must be an abstract class.

So here if some methods are already implemented in some abstract class implementing particular interface and we have to extend functionality for other methods that have been unimplemented,we will need to implement original interface in our class again to get those remaining set of methods.It help in maintaining the contractual rules laid down by an interface.

It will result in rework if were to implement only interface and again overriding all methods with method definitions in our class.

Comment: While this may be true (I think, it's hard for me to follow), it doesn't really answer the question, which is why some classes implement interfaces that their superclass also implements when they wouldn't have to.

Comment: "we will need to implement original interface in our class again to get those remaining set of methods". That's not necessary. If an abstract class implements only some of the methods of an interface, the obligation falls to a non-abstract child class to implement the remainder, but, it is still not necessary for that child class to explicitly say it implements the interface.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose there might be a different way to handle members of the set, the interface, even when supplying the default operation implementation does not serve as a one-size-fits-all. A circular Queue vs. LIFO Queue might both implement the same interface, but their specific operations will be implemented differently, right?

Answer (score -3):

If you only had an abstract class you couldn't make a class of your own which inherits from another class too.

Comment: I think the question is why the concrete implementations explicitly implement the interface again, since it's already "implemented" by the abstract base class.