# Java implements multiple interfaces

Tags: java

Sometimes I see a class implements interfaces `A` and `B`, but `A` has already extended `B`, any reasons behind this ?

For example, the [`AbstractInterruptibleChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractInterruptibleChannel.html) class.

```
public abstract class AbstractInterruptibleChannel
    implements Channel, InterruptibleChannel
```

But [`InterruptibleChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) extends [`Channel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/Channel.html) already:

```
public interface InterruptibleChannel
    extends Channel
```

Comment: Dunno.  Possibly an error by the coder.  API writers are human after all.

Comment: related: [Why do many Collection classes in Java extend the abstract class and implement the interface as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854748/)